# Fit model on the whole dataset is the same as fit model on a splitted dataset continueusly

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

Case 1: let's say I have a defined model (ex: DecisionTreeRegressor ) and I use fit() method on whole train data.

```
model=DecisionTreeRegressor()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Case 2: let's say I split my train data to 3 part and start to fit them continueusly.

```
X_train1,X_train2,X_train3=np.array_split(X_train,3)
y_train1,y_train2,y_train3= np.array_split(y_train,3)

model=DecisionTreeRegressor()
model.fit(X_train1,y_train1)
model.fit(X_train2,y_train2)
model.fit(X_train3,y_train3)
```

In this two scenario I get same model or different?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.